# How to solve linear equation where X and Y is an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a linear relationship between `X` and `Y`, i.e. `Y = m*X + C`, where

- `X = [1,2,3......1024]` ; Y = [Range is unknown]

and I know Y values for two positions of X i.e.

| X | Y (known) |
| --- | --- |
| 216 | 580 |
| 418 | 607 |

and m = 0.1336. I need to estimate Y values for the remaining X positions. Could someone help me with the algorithm or the function that I could use to solve for Y using Python.

Comment: What is `C` for each `X` value?

Comment: C is around 577, i.e. Y intercept when X is around 557

Comment: from these 2 given values C comes out to be `551.14` and `551.15`

Comment: Yes, may be 551

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have m, C and X you can easily calculate Y.

from these 2 given values C comes out to be `551.15`

```
X = list(range(1,1025))
m = 0.1336
C = 551.15

Y = [m*i+C for i in X]

print(Y)

#output
[551.2836, 551.4172, 551.5508, 551.6844,...687.6892, 687.8227999999999, 687.9564] #1024 values
```